# Why I can not umount partition, and why it is busy

Tags: data-recovery

I *accidentally* deleted **whole Documents folder**. I want to use `extundelete` to recover it. As a Ubuntu virgin I spent an hour to correctly write command:

> sudo extundelete /dev/sda6 --restore-directory home/ladislav/Dokumenty

```
ladislav@Ladislav:~$ sudo extundelete /dev/sda6 --restore-directory home/ladislav/Dokumenty
WARNING: Extended attributes are not restored.
WARNING: EXT3_FEATURE_INCOMPAT_RECOVER is set.
```

How can I fix this?

```
The partition should be unmounted to undelete any files without further data loss
If the partition is not currently mounted, this message indicates 
it was improperly unmounted, and you should run fsck before continuing.
If you decide to continue, extundelete may overwrite some of the deleted
files and make recovering those files impossible.  You should unmount the
file system and check it with fsck before using extundelete.
```

**WHEN I TRY TO UNMOUNT IT, THE ANSWER IS BUSY...**

```
ladislav@Ladislav:~$ sudo umount /dev/sda6
umount: /: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))


Would you like to continue? (y/n) 
y
Loading filesystem metadata ... 344 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 30498 descriptors loaded.
Searching for recoverable inodes in directory home/ladislav/Dokumenty ... 
3300 recoverable inodes found.
Looking through the directory structure for deleted files ... 
3300 recoverable inodes still lost.
No files were undeleted.
```

What am I doing wrong? (Besides not keeping a backup of my data?)

Comment: what was your /dev/sda6 partition?

Comment: hard-drive in laptop from which I am writing now (if I understood the question)

Comment: To be honest I have only slight idea what partittion is...

Comment: open gparted locate /dev/sda6 and find out its filesystem and mountpoint.

Comment: gparted installed, command done. I see a window 1st: column /dev/sda6p1. 2nd: ext4, 3rd: 42.91 GB....nothing more

Comment: check its mountpoint.

Comment: there is "!" in there: Warning: 2label: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda6p1. Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock...etc...

Comment: Reboot your pc and then try extundelete.

Comment: @AvinashRaj sda6 is the / partition, and rebooting is not going to help and if anything could increase the possibility of data loss. See the data recovery link I gave - "CAUTION

You should NOT write to the failed device, as it can worsen a hardware failure, and overwrite existant data in case of lost files.

Shut down the affected machine as soon as possible, and restart it from a LiveCD or LiveUSB. Be certain that the "live" cd does not automatically mount any partition or swap space. "

Comment: You cannot unmount the / partition. It is like Windows' C:\ drive. It's the FS root. Unmount that, your entire PC would go down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always run data recovery operations from a live CD.

Once you deleted the files, the physical space on the hard drive is available to write more data, such as tmp files. If the data is over written you will not be able to recover.

In addition, it is usually best to work on a copy of the hard drive.

From your error message

```
umount: /: device is busy.
```

`/dev/sda6` is mounted as root and you will not be able to unmount it.

If you wish to see what is using the hard drive, you can always use lsof

```
sudo lsof /dev/sda6
```

See also - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: i know,i asked the op that what was the mountpoint of /dev/sda6 he replied that there was an exclamatory mark on it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the error message identifies the mount point as /